# Can cellular SIM be part of a LoRa network?

Tags: iot, cellular-network, lora, lorawan

I am doing my FYP and for this I need some information:

- Is it possible to connect a mobile with a LoRa Network via cellular SIM?

Actually, I want to build a mobile software that will operate with a local LoRa network, and the user can connect to the network using this app via cellular network.

Answer (score 2):

No, LTE/GSM/EDGE/Mobile network is a different transmission method than LoRa and thus can not connect to LoRaWAN networks.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think you can . But I think you need another module to include in your project to handle the SIM part and that way you can switch between the Lora  and SIM

Answer (score 1):

LoRaWAN gateways can have a SIM card - usually NBIoT - to provide backhaul in areas that don't have wifi. So that part is possible. But that's for data exiting the LoRaWAN network (or entering it, for downlinks).

But that's it. 4/5G devices can't join a LoRaWAN network.